# Unsure how to order this in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order a result set, it appears really simple, but I'm having a little trouble.

A person can have multiple address types, NULL, Civic or Mailing.
I want anyone who has a NULL address to listed at the top, but then their civic and mailing address to follow.

If you don't have a `null` address, then their civic and/or mailing address comes after anyone who has a `null`.

I've tried ordering by address will just lists all `null`s first, ordering by name, address, will work in part, but won't guarantee that the people will `null`s will be first.

Take this set for example

```
ID  Person      Address
-------------------------
1   Person A    Civic
1   Person A    Mailing
2   Person B    NULL
2   Person B    Civic
2   Person B    Mailing
3   Person C    NULL
3   Person C    Civic
3   Person C    Mailing
```

Should be:

```
ID   Person     Address
-------------------------
2   Person B    NULL
2   Person B    Civic
2   Person B    Mailing
3   Person C    NULL
3   Person C    Civic
3   Person C    Mailing
1   Person A    Civic
1   Person A    Mailing
```

Comment: maybe it is sorted by name

Comment: name or ID. Doesn't matter @TheGameiswar

Comment: @TheGameiswar it's stated in the question `ordering by name, address, will work in part`. Will make it clearer next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Biegeleisen has the right idea with regard to count the number of records where `address IS NULL`. I think the query could be made a tad more elegant (and probably perform a bit better) by using `sum` with a windows clause instead of joining on it with a subquery:

```
SELECT id, person, address
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               person, 
               address, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN PERSON IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER 
                  (PARTITION BY person) AS s
        FROM   addresses) t
ORDER BY s DESC, person ASC, address ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a subquery which determines whether or not each `ID` (person) has a `NULL` value one his addresses.  If a person does have a `NULL` value, then a tally kept will have a sum greater than zero.  Those persons *with* at least one `NULL` address are then ordered first before those persons without at least one `NULL`.  After this, the result set is ordered by `ID` followed by `Address`, as you might already have been doing.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Address IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS hasNull
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.hasNull > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         t1.ID,
         t1.Address
```

Comment: Are you doing in this in production with so many records?  Or do you plan to run this query offline for information purposes?

Comment: it's a production server. It's a big data set in terms of fields that's a union. The query only returns 5k records and takes about 4.5 seconds. The sort doubles the time. Great answer though :)

Comment: The aggregation could be a real performance killer, but I don't see any obvious way to improve it, other than to use a different method which doesn't involve it entirely.  The join could also be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this CTE version.

```
;WITH CTE_1
  AS (SELECT Id, Person, Address, 
               SUM(CASE WHEN PERSON IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER 
              (PARTITION BY person) AS RNO
         FROM   addresses) 
  SELECT Id, Person, Address
  FROM CTE_1
  ORDER BY RNO DESC, person ASC, address ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
select *
from mytable
order by min(case when Address is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by ID), id, Address;
```

Although Sql Server doesn't accept a window function in WHERE it's OK in ORDER BY. So you needn't any subquery here.

Comment: Strange that your post came to the low-quality queue (looking at your rep) and even stranger (looking at my rep) that I'll ask you to add details because code-only answers are not well-accepted here. (but, this is the [accepted way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation) to handle such cases).

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to that @Al.G. Hope an explanation I've added  really helps readers.

Comment: Yeah, it's "no more reviewable". And btw, "simply" is a word that's been removed every time from my own answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too

```
SELECT *
FROM @tab
ORDER BY Person,
         (CASE
              WHEN Address IS NULL
              THEN 'a'
              ELSE Address
          END);
```

Comment: `You can this this one too` - should that be `You can use this` _ordering_ `too`?